# Email OTP verification with firebase authentication in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, email-verification

By default firebase's sending a link to verify the user email, but I want to send a otp with that email. So is there a way to customize that email or send a otp and then once the user entered the correct code on the app get Firebase to mark that user account to email verified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're describing is quite literally what the default Firebase flow does: it send an email with a link that includes a OTP to verify the email address.

You can do a certain amount of [customization of the email action handler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler) page that the emails link to. If that is not enough, you will have to implement your own flow, and can then use the Admin SDK in a secure environment to [mark the user's email as verified](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user).